# Limit variable in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I limit a variable in the creation of a table in sql? For example, I want the number to be lower than 1000, so I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA (
cost int(<1000) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a check constraint:

```
create table data (
    cost int not null,
    check (cost < 1000)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! By any chance would you be able to let me know how to have the date variable in an sql table be so that the user has to type in a date which makes them above 18? Thanks

Comment: @usercomp310101 . . . That is not possible using a check constraint (unless you change the constraint over time).  You need to use a trigger for that.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in MySQL, you need to use at least version 8.0.16 to get support for check constraints. Older versions of MySQL do not support check constraints. Cf. https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/